# What is the inverse function of $f(x)=x/(1-x^2)$

Tags: general-topology, algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

Can you give me a hint for how the inverse function of $f\colon (-1,1)\to \mathbb{R}\colon f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$  looks?

I need to show a homeomorphism!

Comment: You can so homeomorphics with this tool too.  If $f$ is continuous, open (means it maps open sets to open sets),$1-1$ and bijection then it is a homeomorhpism

Comment: yeah How to show the surjection!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inverse of $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258886/inverse-of-fracx1-x2)

Answer (score 3):

You need to show that $f$ is continuous, injective, surjective, and has a continuous inverse. The first two are rather simple and I think you can show that. Showing that $f$ is surjective amounts to using the intermediate value theorem (hint, $f$ is monotonic increasing on $(-1,1)$ and unbounded). To show that $f$ has a continuous inverse, you just need to show that $f$ is an open map - that is $f$ maps open sets to open sets. You should first show that $f$ maps open intervals to open intervals - use the fact, again, that $f$ is monotonic increasing here.

Comment: Please work out for the surjection!

Comment: No, I think you should be able to do that from my hints. If you get stuck while attempting it, feel free to say which part you're stuck on and I'll try to help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{x}{1-x^2} \\
f(x)(1-x^2)&=x \\
f(x)-f(x)x^2&=x \\
0&=f(x)x^2+x-f(x) \\
x&=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4f(x)^2}}{2f(x)}
\end{align}$

Note, as mentioned in the comments below, that this does not give an inverse function, as a function cannot map two values to one point.  Rather, you need to choose the correct inverse and demonstrate that it is indeed an inverse over the interval you are considering.

Comment: This is not even a map! points a single value of x to two different images!

Comment: Yeah, you have to pick the right value.  I'm allowed not to give a complete answer.

Comment: @Tim.Ratigan : I like the fact that you didn't give a complete answer, but I suggest you explain to the OP that s/he must choose + or - and justify why.

Comment: @StefanSmith Good point, I'll do that

Comment: what happens at f(x)=0. There is nothing that maps to x=0. I answered my own question: you can just define a piecewise function, where you define x=0 for f(x)=0, and x=f(x) if x=/=0. Thats the inverse.