# What is exactly the inverse of the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse-function

How do we find the inverse of the function $f:(-1,1)\to \Bbb R$ by $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$?

The problem has been posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554330/what-is-the-inverse-function-of-fx-x-1-x2) and the answer below says "To show that $f$ has a continuous inverse, you just need to show that $f$ is an open map..."

Is it impossible to find the inverse analytically?

Comment: What about solving the quadratic equation (in $x$) $y=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$, and keeping the only solution that is defined for $y=0$?

Comment: The approach suggested by @ClementC. has actually been written down in detail as an answer to the question to which you provided a link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inverse of $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258886/inverse-of-fracx1-x2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For there to be an inverse, the original function has to pass the horizontal line test-there must not be two points on the curve with the same $y$ value.  Your function satisfies that.  A graph (below) is not a proof, but very suggestive.  In this case you can prove it by showing $y' \gt 0$, which shows the function is monotonic.  If you solve $y=\frac x{1-x^2}$ for $x$ you get $$y=\frac x{1-x^2}\\y-x^2y=x\\x^2y+x-y=0\\x=\frac {-1}{2y} \pm \frac {\sqrt {1+4y^2}}{2y}$$  You need to recognize that you can't divide by zero when $y=0$.  We resolve the sign ambiguity by noting that the signs of $x$ and $y$ are always the same.  This will be true with the plus sign so the inverse is the unique $$x=\begin {cases} \frac {-1}{2y} + \frac {\sqrt {1+4y^2}}{2y} & y \neq 0\\0&y=0\end {cases}$$ The resulting curve is a nice reflection in $x=y$

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No it possible to find an inverse. The approach has already had been shown but this will be easier for you to understand. First you should replace $x$ with $y$ and vice versa.

$\frac{y}{1-y^{2}}=x$

Multiply both sides by ${1-y^2}$.

$$x(1-y^2)=y$$

$$x-x{y^2}-y=0$$

$$(-x){y^2}+(-1){y}+(x)=0$$

Now compare this to $ay^2+by+c=0$. Taking the quadratic formula you can solve for $y$ and get two inverse formulas.

So the inverse is split into...

$$y=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ or $$y=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$.

Remeber depending on which inverse function you want to use, pay attention to the range and domain of the original function and its inverse. A graphing calculator like [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) can help.

Comment: Wait so is there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You want to solve, with respect to $x$, the equation
$$
\frac{x}{1-x^2}=y
$$
with the condition that $-1<x<1$. If $y=0$, then $x=0$, so we can assume $y\ne0$. Thus the equation becomes
$$
x^2+\frac{1}{y}x-1=0
$$
Note that this equation has one negative and one positive solution. From the fact that $1-x^2>0$, we need to choose the positive solution for $y>0$ and the negative one for $y<0$. So we have
$$
x=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{-1/y-\sqrt{1/y^2+4}}{2} & \text{if $y<0$} \\[6px]
0 & \text{if $y=0$} \\[6px]
\dfrac{-1/y+\sqrt{1/y^2+4}}{2} & \text{if $y>0$}
\end{cases}
$$

Here's a diagram showing that the inverse function is correct:

[image]

If you follow the blue branch from $-\infty$ to $0$ and the red branch from $0$ to $\infty$, you get exactly the reflection around the bisector of the first and third quadrant of the graph of $f(x)=x/(1-x^2)$ restricted to $(-1,1)$.

Note that for $y>0$ we have
$$
0<\dfrac{-1/y+\sqrt{1/y^2+4}}{2}<1
$$
because, setting $t=1/y$ this is equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{t^2+4}>t\\
\sqrt{t^2+4}<2+t
\end{cases}
$$
The first inequality is obviously true; squaring the second one, we get
$$
t^2+4<4+4t+t^2
$$
which is true as well. Similarly, you can prove that, for $y<0$
$$
-1<\dfrac{-1/y-\sqrt{1/y^2+4}}{2}<0
$$

Comment: Interesting that you needed 3 pieces in your piecewise function, while Ross Millikan only needed 2

Comment: @Ovi If you pull $y^2$ out of the square root, you see that there's no difference. I preferred to keep the function dependent on $1/y$, which helps in the next part.

Answer (score -2):

Inverse function is 
$$ x = y/(1-y^2)$$
solving for y(x) we can choose any one of the two valid inverse functions
$$ y(x)= -\frac{1}{2x}\pm \sqrt { 1+\frac{1}{(2x)^2} }$$

Comment: How can an invertible function have two distinct inverse functions? Which one will be the one which has the domain of $f$ as its range?

Comment: One of the two, either/or choice, an inverse is (negative) reciprocal of the other.

Comment: The plot by Egreg very clearly shows $two$ choices,red and blue, I am of same view. if you started with a cubic you would face same (like di- ) trichotomy of domains/ranges of inverse functions.