# Inverse of $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

How did Munkres (page 104 – new international edition) invert the function
$$
  F(x) = \frac{x}{1-x^2} \,, \quad x \in (-1,1)
$$
for
$$
  G(y) = \frac{2y}{1 + \sqrt{1+4y^2}} \,, \quad y \in \mathbb{R} \,?
$$

Looks like some trig-substitution but cannot see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual method to obtain the inverse is to let $F(x)=y$, interchange $x$ and $y$, and solve for $y$. Thus we solve
$$x=\frac{y}{1-y^2}$$ 
for $y$:
\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{y}{1-y^2}\\
\implies x-xy^2&=y\\
\implies xy^2+y-x&=0\\
\implies y^2+\tfrac1xy-1&=0\\
\implies(y+\tfrac1{2x})^2&=\frac{1+4x^2}{4x^2}\qquad\text{(completing the square)}\\[4pt]
\implies y+\frac{1}{2x} &=\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}\\
\implies y&=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x},
\end{align*}
which is equivalent to $G(x)$ if you multiply the top and bottom by $-1-\sqrt{1+4x^2}$.

---

Think of this last extra step as similar to *realising the denominator* when you multiply by the complex conjugate. You can also get to it straight away by using the less well-known [Muller's version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muller%27s_method) of the quadratic formula:

$$ x= \frac{-2c}{b\mp\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}.$$

(This version has the advantage that if $a=0$, you still get valid roots).

Comment: Thanks - missed the multiplication by $-1-\sqrt{1+4x^2}$ top and bottom and thought I'd missed some.

Comment: @undefined I know, it's a weird algebraic trick in this context. I first came across it for the proof of that Muller version of the quadratic formula, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$y=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$$ so we get
$$y-yx^2=x$$ or
$$x^2+\frac{x}{y}-1=0$$ using the quadratic formula we get
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2y}\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4y^2}+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

To invert the function $y=F(x)$, you need to solve for $y$ in the equation $x=F(y)$.  So solve for $y$ in
$$ x = \frac{y}{1-y^2} \implies 0 = y^2 x + y - x \implies y = F^{-1}(x) = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}}{2x} $$
where the last equality is quadratic formula